# Table with Bullet points and coordinating counts

Tags: r, r-markdown, multiline, kableextra, multivalue

It's been a while since I have posted. I am trying to create a table that looks like this:

[image: Desired table]

However, I have been unable to complete this task. This table is part of a r-Markdown document. here is the code I have so far:

```
library(kableExtra)

Fact_Fig19_20 <- data.frame(Facts=c("\\# of Dual Enrollment Students (2019-2020)","\\# of Dual Enrollment Students enrolled as Dual (2020-2021) Retention","\\# of Dual Enrollment Staudents enrolled as FTF in Fall 2020","\\# of Dual Enrollment Students enrolled as FTF in Spring 2021", "\\# Dual Enrollment Students enrolled Non-SCTCS \\n 
                              \\begin{itemize}
                                \\item - Non-SCTCS 2-year\\n
                                 \\item - Non-SCTCS 4-year
                              \\end{itemize}","\\# of Dual Enrollment Students Unknown Status"), Counts=c(100, 60, 10, 10,10,10)) #the fourth entry in this vector needs to be broken down into 5 #and 5
```

More Specifically I am having trouble with the 4th line of the table where 2 values exist in the same cell. Any guidance will be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the latex table as pdf, so you could try a manual approach:

````
```{=latex}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|r| } 
 \hline
 \# of Dual Enrollment Students (2019-2020) & 100\\ \hline 
 \# of Dual Enrollment Students enrolled as Dual (2020-2021) Retention & 60 \\ \hline 
 \# of Dual Enrollment Students enrolled as FTF in Fall 2020 & 10  \\ \hline
 \# of Dual Enrollment Students enrolled as FTF in Spring 2021 & 10  \\ \hline
 \# Dual Enrollment Students enrolled Non-SCTCS  &  \\ 
   \hspace{10mm}- Non-SCTCS 2-year &  5\\
   \hspace{10mm}- Non-SCTCS 4-year &  5\\ \hline
\# of Dual Enrollment Students Unknown Status & 10 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```
````

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could make a latex chunk in R-markdown. Thank you!